# Firewall rule to route traffic from only 1 of 2 IPs on server

Tags: rhel, routing, firewall

Trying to config firewalld on RHEL 7 running on AWS with 2 Dynamic IP sets, "IP Set A" and "IP Set B".  Each IP set consists of an internal and external IP address.  I have 2 http servers running on this machine and I only want to divert traffic that comes into the server over one of them "IP Set B" to another port (8083).

I issue these commands for "IP Set B" (one for the internal IP and one the external IP):

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=80:addr=34.224.209.140:proto=tcp:toport=8083
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=80:addr=10.0.0.169:proto=tcp:toport=8083
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

And I get:

```
public (active)
 target: default
 icmp-block-inversion: no
 interfaces: eth0
 sources:
 services: ssh dhcpv6-client mysql
 ports: 21/tcp 8083/tcp
 protocols:
 masquerade: yes
 forward-ports: port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8083:toaddr=
 source-ports:
 icmp-blocks:
 rich rules:
```

My updates DO cause the routing to occur for "IP Set A", BUT it is also happening for "IP Set B".  I also note that my references to "addr=10.0.0.169" and "addr=34.224.209.140" do NOT show up on the outputted list of rules. Any help appreciated!